# UEFI Firmware Update Failed (18.04 dual boot with Windows 7)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, thinkpad, firmware, fwupd

Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th, Windows 7

I just set up a dual boot with 18.04, and some UEFI incompatibility put me in limbo between OSs; I had to "try ubuntu" and use boot repairfor it to recognize the Ubuntu install and boot from it.

Now everything has been working, except for the firmware update: trying to run it on the software center gives "Unable to update `Thinkpad X1 Carbon 4th / Yoga 1st'".

Then, using fwupdmgr, I get this:

```
> sudo fwupdmgr update
Downloading 0.1.38 for 20FB004JUS System Firmware...
Updating 0.1.38 on 20FB004JUS System Firmware...
Decompressing...          [*********************************]
Authenticating...         [*********************************]
Scheduling...             [*********************************]
UEFI firmware update failed:
{error #0} libfwup.c:1005 get_paths():
could not find shim or fwup on ESP:
No such file or directory
{error #1} libfwup.c:1143 set_up_boot_next():
could not find paths for shim and fwup:
No such file or directory
```

Hopefully this isn't an indication of a serious firmware incompatibility.

Anyone have advice? Thank you.

Comment: You can't install that update with the OS installed in Legacy mode. Running the Windows executable in Windows 7 will probably fail either. In order to update the UEFI you may need to use other methods. Check the manufacturer's website for alternatives (usually by using bootable media).

Comment: And both OSes can be installed in UEFI mode. There's no incompatibility.

Comment: Thank you. I could not find any alternative methods, but I rebooted and chose 'advanced options for Ubuntu' in the grub menu, then ran the various clean/update tools... it seems to have fixed it.

Comment: No, it didn't but actually there's nothing to "fix". It didn't installed the firmware and is likely to not propose it again in the future. But if the computer works fine then no update needed anyway (unless it patches a severe security flaw). I still recommend searching for the update at the manufacturer's website (look for "BIOS¨ even if it's clearly UEFI), read the changelog and then decide whether to apply it or not.

Comment: Alright, thanks for following up. Here's the Lenovo site : https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20fb-20fc/downloads , but it seems that even in a general search there are only firmware updates for Windows. Will I have to do some cross-platform maneuver to apply an update?

Comment: The one that says "bootable CD" is actually OS independent. It's an ISO file that can be burned into a CD by any CD Burning app in any OS (For Ubuntu: Brasero, K3b, etc.). Then it's just a matter of booting from that CD. The "for Windows 10..." part is nonsense ;)

Comment: Alright, well last catch, I don't have a CD drive. Can this be converted to something I can burn on a USB? Thanks.

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-13-E-and/Updating-the-BIOS-via-bootable-USB/td-p/1139231 In this thread one ArchLinux user described a method that should work but it's confusing. I *think* MKUSB ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb ) can make it from that ISO. One of the following features *may* work: "Cloning ISO file" or "Extracting Windows installer", probably the latter.